# Get key value of dictionary

Tags: javascript, key-value

How do I get the value from a javascript dictionary? (I don't even know if it's called a dictionary in javascript)

I get the following object  (friends) from the facebook sdk. How do I, for example, loop through the names?

```
{data: [{id: "xxxxx", name: "Friend name"}, {id: "xxxxx", name: "Friend name"}]}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In JavaScript dictionaries are objects. To access object properties you may use either dot notation or square brackets notation. To iterate an array you may use simple `for` loop.

```
var obj = {
        data: [{
            id: "xxxxx",
            name: "Friend name"
        }, {
            id: "xxxxx",
            name: "Friend name"
        }]
    };

for (var i = 0, len = obj.data.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(obj.data[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Loop through the data array within the object that wraps the whole thing. Then target the name with object dot notation:

```
for (var i = 0, l = obj.data.length; i < l; i++) {
  console.log(obj.data[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the `data` array like this:

```
var obj = {data: [{id: "xxxxx", name: "Friend name"}, {id: "xxxxx", name: "Friend name"}]};

//loop thru objects in data
obj.data.forEach(function(itm)  {
   console.log(itm.name);
});
```

Comment: @Andy Suuuure. Let's go with that. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

```js
const obj = {
  data: [{
    id: "xxxxx",
    name: "Friend name"
  }, {
    id: "xxxxx",
    name: "Friend name"
  }]
}

obj.data.map(x => console.log(x.name))
```